# Synchronous call

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a web application where my app's front-end uses angular js. I have a method in the angular js controller which is called on-click of a button. And in that method, I call the angular service to send a request to the Java controller. The logic looks like this

```
var submitted= true;

submitted= sampleService.sampleMethod(sampleParam);
alert(submitted);
if(!submitted){
    //some action
}
```

The service will return true if the request was successful, false if it failed. 
The issue that i'm having is that I get the alert before the request is sent (the alert says undefined). So regardless the response, the if condition fails.

Is there a solution for this issue?

edit :

The sample method

```
this.sampleMethod = function (sampleServiceMethod, obj){

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({

              templateUrl: 'example.html',
              controller: 'anotherController',
              resolve: {
                modalServiceMethod: function () {
                  return sampleServiceMethod;
                }
              }
            });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (modalServiceMethod) {
            modalServiceMethod(obj).then(function(response){
                $window.location = response.sampleUrl;
            }, function(err) {
                $log.error("error occured", err);
            });
         }, function () {
            $log.debug('error on: ' + new Date());
         }).finally(function() {
                return false;
         });

    };
```

Basically if the request is successful, the page will be redirected. But I need the return value of false during failure to make necessary changes.

Comment: what's the `sampleMethod` code like?

Answer (score 1):

** Update #1 **
I could help better if you organize and rename the code a bit. Hard to follow with all the names when they don't mean anything.

As a first thing try adding this return statement before the modalInstance::

```
return modalInstance.result.then(function (modalServiceMethod) {
            modalServiceMethod(obj).then(function(response){
                $window.location = response.sampleUrl;
            }, function(err) {
                $log.error("error occured", err);
            });
         }, function () {
            $log.debug('error on: ' + new Date());
         }).finally(function() {
                return false;
         });
```

** Original answer **

Why do you declare submitted as true and then run run the function on it?

It looks like this function:

```
sampleService.sampleMethod(sampleParam);
```

return undefined.

Add the code of that function so we can look into it.

If that function sends a request to the server to fetch data, it will be returned as a promise. in that case your code should be:

```
    sampleService.sampleMethod(sampleParam).then(function(response){ 
      submitted = response.data;
      conole.log(submitted)
    });
```

but the fact you get undefined in your alert and not a promise object, indicates you probably missed a "return" statement in your sampleService.sampleMethod(sampleParam) method. that method should look something like this:

```
function sampleMethod(param) { 
  return $http.get('url', param)
}
```

Comment: I have added the sample method here. I'm using another enpoint.js to send the request but it looks almost the same as the sampleMethod in your comment.